# How to use HuggingFace Model on my own dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, speech-to-text

I have a small data that cosists of voice recordings. My task is to convert them to the text by using pretrained model MMS Facebook from hugging face (SPEECH TO TEXT). [MMS Model](https://huggingface.co/spaces/mms-meta/MMS/blob/main/asr.py). How can I implement it in Google Colab? What should be my plan? I would like to get any suggestions and recommendations.

I have just installed necessary libraries

```
!pip install transformers
!pip install datasets>=2.6.1
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
!pip install librosa
!pip install evaluate>=0.30
!pip install jiwer
!pip install gradio
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are a beginner when it comes to Huggingface. Maybe follow their tutorials/courses: https://huggingface.co/learn/audio-course/chapter0/introduction

That will probably be the best starting point.
Otherwise, learn the following steps:

1. How to load a HF-Model (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/model_doc/mms#overview)
2. How to load my own dataset (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.13.1/en/quickstart#audio)
3. How to use the Huggingface Trainer (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/main_classes/trainer#trainer)

There will be a lot of things you need to learn either way.
Hope it helps !